# Unknown error thrown from JBOSS 7.1.1 version while deploying war file to it

Tags: jboss

Cannot get how this error come out. No reason no brain sence from te

> 17:52:58,395 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] JBoss Modules version 1.1.1.GA
>   17:52:58,604 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] JBoss MSC version 1.0.2.GA
>   17:52:58,665 INFO  [org.jboss.as] JBAS015899: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final
>   "Brontes" starting 17:52:59,554 INFO  [org.xnio] XNIO Version 3.0.3.GA
>   17:52:59,554 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] JBAS015888: Creating http
>   management service using socket-binding (management-http) 17:52:59,563
>   INFO  [org.xnio.nio] XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.0.3.GA
>   17:52:59,570 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] JBoss Remoting version
>   3.2.3.GA 17:52:59,590 INFO  [org.jboss.as.logging] JBAS011502: Removing bootstrap log handlers 17:52:59,593 INFO 
>   [org.jboss.as.configadmin] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 26)
>   JBAS016200: Activating ConfigAdmin Subsystem 17:52:59,617 INFO 
>   [org.jboss.as.naming] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 38) JBAS011800:
>   Activating Naming Subsystem 17:52:59,624 INFO  [org.jboss.as.osgi]
>   (ServerService Thread Pool -- 39) JBAS011940: Activating OSGi
>   Subsystem 17:52:59,633 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan]
>   (ServerService Thread Pool -- 31) JBAS010280: Activating Infinispan
>   subsystem. 17:52:59,655 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (ServerService
>   Thread Pool -- 44) JBAS013101: Activating Security Subsystem
>   17:52:59,667 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-6)
>   JBAS013100: Current PicketBox version=4.0.7.Final 17:52:59,719 INFO 
>   [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS011802: Starting
>   Naming Service 17:52:59,722 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC
>   service thread 1-5) JBAS015400: Bound mail session
>   [java:jboss/mail/Default] 17:52:59,725 INFO 
>   [org.jboss.as.webservices] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 48)
>   JBAS015537: Activating WebServices Extension 17:52:59,782 INFO 
>   [org.jboss.as.connector] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS010408: Starting
>   JCA Subsystem (JBoss IronJacamar 1.0.9.Final) 17:52:59,812 INFO 
>   [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread
>   Pool -- 27) JBAS010403: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class
>   org.h2.Driver (version 1.3) 17:52:59,861 INFO 
>   [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread
>   Pool -- 27) JBAS010404: Deploying non-JDBC-compliant driver class
>   com.mysql.jdbc.Driver (version 5.1) 17:52:59,927 INFO 
>   [org.jboss.ws.common.management.AbstractServerConfig] (MSC service
>   thread 1-5) JBoss Web Services - Stack CXF Server 4.0.2.GA
>   17:53:00,363 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC
>   service thread 1-3) JBAS015012: Started FileSystemDeploymentService
>   for directory D:\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone\deployments
>   17:53:00,363 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC
>   service thread 1-5) JBAS015012: Started FileSystemDeploymentService
>   for directory
>   D:\workspace\eclipse.metadata.plugins\org.jboss.ide.eclipse.as.core\JBoss_7.1_Runtime_Server1402151223281\deploy
>   17:53:00,393 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-8)
>   JBAS017100: Listening on localhost/ 127.0.0 .1:4447 17:53:00,393 INFO 
>   [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS017100: Listening
>   on / 127 .0. 0.1:10101 17:53:00,413 INFO 
>   [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol] (MSC service thread 1-5)
>   Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-loca lhost-127. 0.0.1-7070
>   17:53:00,525 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources]
>   (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS010400: Bound data source [java:/MySqlDS]
>   17:53:00,525 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources]
>   (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS010400: Bound data source
>   [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS] 17:53:00,554 INFO  [org.jboss.as]
>   (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015951: Admin console listening on http:
>   // 127 .0.0.1: 10102 17:53:00,554 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller
>   Boot Thread) JBAS015874: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" started in
>   2443ms - Started 139 of 215 services (74 services are passive or
>   on-demand) 17:53:15,376 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner]
>   (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS015003: Found HelloRest.war in
>   deployment directory. To trigger deployment create a file called
>   HelloRest.war.dodeploy 17:53:15,412 INFO 
>   [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS015876:
>   Starting deployment of "HelloRest.war" 17:53:16,843 INFO 
>   [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS016002:
>   Processing weld deployment HelloRest.war 17:53:16,853 ERROR
>   [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-4) MSC00001: Failed
>   to start service jboss.deployment.unit."HelloRest.war".POST_MODULE:
>   org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service
>   jboss.deployment.unit."HelloRest.war".POST_MODULE: Failed to process
>   phase POST_MODULE of deployment "HelloRest.war"   at
>   org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:119)
>   [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]     at
>   org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
>   [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]     at
>   org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
>   [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>   [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>   [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>   [rt.jar:1.7.0_51] Caused by:
>   java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range:
>   0     at java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]    at
>   org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:460)
>     at
>   org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456)
>     at
>   org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
>     at
>   org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120)
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.jaxrs.deployment.JaxrsScanningProcessor.checkDeclaredApplicationClassAsServlet(JaxrsScanningProcessor.java:288)
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.jaxrs.deployment.JaxrsScanningProcessor.scanWebDeployment(JaxrsScanningProcessor.java:155)
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.jaxrs.deployment.JaxrsScanningProcessor.deploy(JaxrsScanningProcessor.java:104)
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113)
>   [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]     ... 5 more
>
> 17:53:16,868 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads -
>   2) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "HelloRest.war" was rolled back
>   with failure message {"JBAS014671: Failed services" =>
>   {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"HelloRest.war\".POST_MODULE" =>
>   "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service
>   jboss.deployment.unit.\"HelloRest.war\".POST_MODULE: Failed to process
>   phase POST_MODULE of deployment \"HelloRest.war\""}} 17:53:16,870 INFO
>   [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS014774:
>   Service status report JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:
>   service jboss.deployment.unit."HelloRest.war".POST_MODULE:
>   org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service
>   jboss.deployment.unit."HelloRest.war".POST_MODULE: Failed to process
>   phase POST_MODULE of deployment "HelloRest.war"
>
> 17:53:16,879 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner]
>   (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) {"JBAS014653: Composite operation
>   failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-2"
>   => {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"HelloRest.war\".POST_MODULE" =>
>   "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service
>   jboss.deployment.unit.\"HelloRest.war\".POST_MODULE: Failed to process
>   phase POST_MODULE of deployment \"HelloRest.war\""}}}} 17:53:16,914
>   INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7)
>   JBAS015877: Stopped deployment HelloRest.war in 40ms

**PERSON JAVA CLASS:**

```
package rest.hello;

public class Person implements Speakable {

@Override
public String getName() {
    return "My Name";
}

}
```

**SPEACKABLE Interface:**

```
package rest.hello;

import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/person")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
@Consumes(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public interface Speakable {

@GET
@Path("/name")
public String getName();
```

}

**POM File**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>org.jboss.tools</groupId>
<artifactId>hellorest</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>hellorest</name>
<description>hellorest</description>
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>${basedir}/src/main/java</directory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <warSourceDirectory>${basedir}/WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>maven-central</id>
        <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>maven2-repository.java.net</id>
        <name>Java.net Repository for Maven</name>
        <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2/</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>java.net2</id>
        <name>Java.net</name>
        <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/java.net2</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>ejb3-persistence</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1.GA</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.1.GA</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.6.ga</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.16</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1.GA</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your eclipse, click on the project > properties > project facets

uncheck the jax-rs option and try again